# PagespeedInsights shows defer offscreen images even when image is lazy loaded?

Tags: html, css, seo, lazy-loading, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeedInsights shows defer offscreen images even when the image below is lazyloaded

```
<img data-src="https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in/images/successfull-stories/australian-Patient.jpg" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive lazyloaded" src="https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in/images/successfull-stories/australian-Patient.jpg">
```

Can someone please explain what the above code means especially this part:

```
 class="img-responsive lazyloaded"
```

How can I defer this image?

Defer this image

```
<img data-src="https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in/images/successfull-stories/australian-Patient.jpg" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive lazyloaded" src="https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in/images/successfull-stories/australian-Patient.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code snippet is directly coming from the server side rendered HTML, both the `src` attribute value as well as `data-src` attribute are the same.

This then means that the browser will start to fetch the `src` resource right away:
https://www.healinghandsclinic.co.in/images/successfull-stories/australian-Patient.jpg

And if that image is not visible within the viewport (as used by Lighthouse), it will still end up competing for bandwidth with other (image & non-image) resources.

Hence PageSpeed Insights (PSI)/Lighthouse's recommendation to defer off-screen images.

However, given the CSS classes used on your image element (`class="img-responsive lazyloaded"`), it's likely that the code snippet you're sharing is actually the end result after some lazyloading JS library loaded the image.

The same theory as above still applies: the initial fallback image (which might just be a low-quality version of your image or a 1x1 placeholder) might have ended up being downloaded, and that was discovered by PSI.

Without additional info, it's hard to say which image was initially found by PSI.

#### Solution

Regardless of your scenario, there is a 2-step best practice & solution here:

- remove your JS lazyloading library;
- and then go with native lazyloading (which just means adding a `loading="lazy"` attribute to your `<img>`);
- it might be convenient to also change CSS bg images (if you have any) into `<img>` as that gives you more loading options/control

As using native lazyloading allows you to remove JavaScript, it will then improve your JS performance and TBT (lab data/Lighthouse metric) and INP (field data/part of Core Web Vitals) as well!

#### Resources

This is an old Google article that talks about JS libraries:
https://web.dev/articles/lazy-loading-images

But with native lazyloading, we don't need JS anymore (a new Google article on this subject):
https://web.dev/articles/browser-level-image-lazy-loading#why_browser-level_lazy_loading

Code example and support in all major browsers (for both `<img>` and `<iframe>`):
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7129755923555737601/
When/what to lazyload:
https://www.erwinhofman.com/blog/to-lazyload-above-the-fold-images/